# Cassandra how to filter hex values in blob field

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE associations (
    someHash blob,
    someValue int,
    someOtherField text
    PRIMARY KEY (someHash, someValue)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (someValue ASC);
```

The inserts to this table have someHash as a hex value, like 0xA0000000000000000000000000000001, 0xA0000000000000000000000000000002, etc.

If a query needs to find all rows with 0xA0000000000, what's the recommended Cassandra way to do it?

Comment: When you query, do you know the value of someValue, ?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your query is that it does not take into account limitations of Cassandra, namely:

- someHash is a partition key column
- The partition key columns [in `WHERE` clause] support only two operators: `=` and `IN` (i.e. exact match)

In other words, your schema is designed in such a way, that effectively query should say: "let's retrieve all possible keys [from all nodes], let's filter them (type not important here) and then retrieve values for keys that match predicate". This is a full-scan of some sort and is not what Cassandra is best at. You can try using [UDFs](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/user-defined-functions-in-cassandra-3-0) to do some data transformation (trimming someHash), but I would expect it to work well only with trivial amounts of data.

Golden rule of Cassandra is **"query first"**: if you have such a use-case, schema should be designed accordingly - sub-key you want to query by should be actual partition key (full someHash value can be part of clustering key).

BTW, same limitation applies to most `maps` in programming: you can't do lookup by part of key (because of hashing).

Answer (score 0):

Following your 0xA0000000000 example directly:

You could split up someHash into 48 bits (6 bytes) and 80 bits (10 bytes) parts.

```
PRIMARY KEY ((someHash_head, someHash_tail), someValue)
```

The IN will then have 16 values, from 0xA00000000000 to 0xA0000000000F.